# Указатель на лямбду как аргумент функции. С++

Tags: c++, lambda

В общем, у меня есть функция show, которая принимает в качестве параметра лямбда функцию.

```
template <typename T, class f>
void show(T *beg, T *end, f lambda)
```

Мне нужно чтобы моя функция принимала лямбду не как шаблон, а как конкретно указатель на функцию.

Хочу перегрузить свою функцию show для обычных лямбд, и для лямбд-предикатов, много вариантов перепробовал, всё равно пишет, что моя функция не перегружена под аргумент "lambda []bool(int)->bool". Проще говоря: хочу сделать так, чтобы лямбда передавалась не по шаблону, а по конкретному параметру.

Просьба вариант с объектом function не предлагать, я хочу узнать есть ли вариант обойтись без этого.

Comment: У лямбды нет заранее известного типа и поэтому ее не получится передавать "по конкретному параметру".

Comment: *"Хочу перегрузить свою функцию show для обычных лямбд, и для лямбд-предикатов"* - вот это непонятный момент, что такое по-вашему "лямбда-предикат"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под  лямбдой-предикатом подразумевается функция возвращающая bool, то проще всего использовать следующее решение:

```
template <typename Iterator, class F, class LambdaResult>
void show( Iterator beg, Iterator end, F lambda, LambdaResult*)
{
    std::cout<<" result of lambda is: " << typeid(LambdaResult).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename Iterator, class F>
void show( Iterator beg, Iterator end, F lambda, void*)
{
    std::cout<<" result of lambda result is void" << std::endl;
}
template <typename Iterator, class F>
void show( Iterator beg, Iterator end, F lambda, bool*)
{
    std::cout<<" result of lambda result is bool" << std::endl;
}

template <typename Iterator, class F>
void show( Iterator beg, Iterator end, F lambda)
{
    typedef decltype( lambda(*beg) ) LambdaResult;
    show( beg, end, lambda, (LambdaResult*) NULL ); // dispatch implementations...
}
```

Можно, написать решение без лишнего перевызова функции (с использованием std::enable_if), это будет сложнее читаться (ИМХО).

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так, однако вывод параметра `T` в таком варианте работать не будет, так как лямбда функция сама по себе не является указателем на функцию, хотя и может к нему приводиться когда не имеет контекста:

```
template <typename T>
void show(T *beg, T *end, void ( * lambda )(T)) {}

show<int>(nullptr, nullptr, [](int) {});
```